# * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Failed to find Build Tools revision 29.0.2

Tags: android, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
`Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Failed to find Build Tools revision 29.0.2`

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
`Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

[image]

[image]

Comment: click on pub get and  try again

Answer (score 7):

You need to download that version of the SDK build tools.
The easiest way is by using Android Studio.

1. Open the Preferences window by clicking File > Settings (on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences).
2. In the left panel, click **Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK**
3. Click on the **SDK tools** pane
4. Check ** Show Package Details**
5. Under the Android SDK Build tools check the specific version you need. *(in this case, it is 29.0.2)* you can even update if you need.
6. Click Ok
   This should download the versions selected.

For more information check this link:

[Update IDE and Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update)

Answer (score 5):

1. Add these lines:

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 30
       buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
   }
   ```

   in `android>>app>>build.gradle`
2. Go to

   `Tools>>SDKManager>>AndroidSDk>>SDKTool>>Android SDK Command-line > Tool(latest)`

   Check the CheckBox, then apply, and after Installing run the code in android phone.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just fix it by deleting .gradle from C:/User/Gustavo/, i my case this problem was happened when i upgrade the flutter version

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines:
in android>>app>>build.gradle

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
}

try this ....

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with "**Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.2**".
I solved it by downloading the **"build tools 30.0.2"** (https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-build-tools.html) and putting it in my sdk folder in **"flutter\Sdk\build-tools"**.